# Getting the following error while creating table using two nodes "Failed to get Pooled connection"

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgres-xc

I have configured two gtm (gtm1,gtm2) in two different machine using postgres-xc. And configured coordinator1,datanode1 in gtm1 machine and coordinator2, datanode2 in gtm2 machine.

I have logged in both coordinator servers and created the datanode1 and datanode2 in both server. When I try to create the tables using the both node I am getting the error:

> Failed to get Pooled connection

and when I check the datanode1 log file found the error like this:

> unexpected EOF on client connection

Comment: When i try to add table after removing the datanode2 and coordinator2 in coordinator1, able to create the table, same for coordinator1.

Answer (score 1):

The `max_pool_size`, `max_connections` and `max_prepared_transactions` parameters need to be set differently on coordinator and data nodes. On coordinators `max_pool_size` should be at least `max_connections` multiplied by the total number of data nodes (see [Postgres-XL Specific Parameters](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/pg-xc-specifics.html) and [Starting Postgres-XL Cluster](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/server-start.html))